# Integration by parts with vectors and matrices

Tags: calculus

I need to integrate by parts the product of a vector (v) times the divergence of a matrix A. I think the solution is:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
\int_\Omega \textbf{v} \cdot \div(A)dV=\int_{\partial\Omega} (\textbf{n}\otimes \textbf{v}): A dS-\int_\Omega \grad(\textbf{v}):AdV 
$$

but I would like to be able to understand this and derive the equation myself. I would like to understand why the integration by parts leads to those double dot products, but also how to apply the divergence theorem with tensors.
Thanks for the help and sorry if the notation is not correct, it's been a while since I had to use tensors.

Comment: What does the colon mean? Is $\otimes$ different from a vector product?

Comment: Usually in differential equations, the tensor product is taken to mean matrix whose values are the coefficients in the usual tensor product.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you have something like that hard to understand, return to the formula component by component.

$$v \cdot div(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \times div(A)_i = \sum_{i=1}^n\left( v_i \times \sum_{j=1}^n \partial_j a_{ij} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n v_i\partial_j a_{ij} $$

You apply the integration by part, and you get, on the border

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n n_jv_i a_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (n\otimes v)_{ji} a_{ij} =  (n\otimes v): A$$

And on the domain

$$- \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n  a_{ij} \partial_jv_i = grad(v) : A$$